# how to update GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1

Tags: android, sdk, admob

i am really confused with this question! After searching everywhere and without getting a good answer, i come here to ask you. In my Admob Account appears a Warning message that says: "Remember that, as of August 1, 2014, all application upgrades and new applications that are uploaded to Google Play Store must comply with the provision on advertising ID policy Developer Program. Upgrade your SDK to the version of Google Play SDK mobile ads to comply with this provision and take advantage of new features, including automatic updates and bug fixes."

i buy a code source(android) with GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1 
and there's a update on admob about google play servcie or i don't know i'm not a programmer,and i need to know if i need to update this sdk version or ..
please anyone to help 
I don t know nothing about add codes or something like that if there's a Tuto please,i know hot to update google plays ervice lib ( it's just to replace the old lib with the new lib is that simple ) please any help

Answer (score 0):

> ...all application upgrades and new applications that are uploaded to Google Play Store...

Now, I'm not a lawyer, so take my layman opinion for what it's worth, but I'm reading this to mean that this only applies to "**upgrades** and **new applications**" that are uploaded to the Google Play Store.

If your application was uploaded and published before that date, then you should have nothing to worry about.

In other words, if you do pay a developer to upgrade or fix your application between August 1st, 2014 and some later time, then it will be time to ask him to upgrade that library at the same time he does that other work, but if your application hasn't changed and if the last version has already been published before August 1, 2014, then you should be in the clear.

*Again, that's just my lay opinion, I'm not a lawyer. Etc.*

Answer (score 0):

If your app is already released before August 1st, it will continue to serve ads using the old SDK without any problem. And you will continue to get revenue from Admob. The new policy is that, after August 1st, the Play Store will no longer accept new apps nor updates to old apps, that use the old Admob SDK. So if you want to update your app later, you'll have to use Google Play Service to serve ads.

Also, please make sure that you migrate from the legacy Admob to the new Admob before August 31st. More info can be found in this link: https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/6024444?hl=en